# How to decrease the memory limit in R?

Tags: r, memory, limit

I am running my code in R in a server and I do not want to use all memory. However, it seems that the memory.limit function only works to increase the memory limit, not to decrease it

This is the script I used so far:

```
memory.limit()
[1] 1.759219e+13
```

```
memory.limit(size = 150000)
Warning message:
In memory.limit(size = 150000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

Comment: The details section of `?memory.limit` gives some solutions, have you tried these?

Comment: I visited the recommended session, but it says that "Memory limits can only be increased."

Comment: Yes, it's correct that the limits can't be decreased while running, but either the command-line flag or the environment variable allow you to set a lower limit when starting R